# Invalid set index 'texture' (on base: 'null instance')

Tags: gd, godot, gdscript

Invalid set index 'texture' (on base: 'null instance') with value of type 'StreamTexture'.

```
extends Panel

var ItemClass = preload("res://Item.tscn")
var item = "res://Blue Jeans.png"

func _ready():
    if randi() % 2 == 0:
        item = ItemClass.instance()
        add_child(item)
```

```
extends TextureRect

func _ready():
    if randi() % 2 == 0:
        $TextureRect.texture = load("res://Blue Jeans.png")
    else:
        $TextureRect.texture = load("res://Brown Boots.png")
```

I followed the exact tutorial on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHYb63ppHmk
but it seems to debug differently.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$TextureRect.texture = load("res://Blue Jeans.png")`
```

Loads a png as a `StreamTexture` using `load`, and tries to set it to the `texture` property of whatever `$TextureRect` is.

But the error says that there is no `texture` property on a null instance. Thus, the problem is that `$TextureRect` is a null instance.

So what does the expression `$TextureRect` do? It is equivalent to `get_node("TextureRect")`. In other words it is trying to get a child node called `"TextureRect"`. And it is getting null…

Does the node on which the script is attached have a child node called `"TextureRect"`? You didn't share how the scene tree looks like, but I suspect it does not.

The script you shared says `extends TextureRect`, thus the script would be attached to a `TextureRect`. However, that is not what they do in the tutorial. In the tutorial the script is attached to a `Node2D` that has the `TextureRect` as child. You can see that at [4:10 on the tutorial video](https://youtu.be/FHYb63ppHmk?t=250).

If you want to set the texture of the node on which the script is attached, set `texture` directly:

```
texture = load("res://Blue Jeans.png")`
```

Or if you rather be explicit, use `self`:

```
self.texture = load("res://Blue Jeans.png")`
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to follow the tutorial, then put the script on a node that has the `TextureRect` as a child (called `"TextureRect"`), and there `$TextureRect` would work.